# while running selendroid code showing this error....Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException

Tags: android

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: The requested application under test is not configured in selendroid server.
io.selendroid.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: The requested application under test is not configured in selendroid server.
    at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.createNewTestSession(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:205)
    at io.selendroid.server.handler.CreateSessionHandler.handle(CreateSessionHandler.java:42)
    at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidServlet.handleRequest(SelendroidServlet.java:143)
    at io.selendroid.server.BaseServlet.handleHttpRequest(BaseServlet.java:67)
    at io.selendroid.server.http.ServerHandler.channelRead(ServerHandler.java:50)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:148)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:125)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 2):

1.Run `java -jar selendroid-standalone-0.14.0-with-dependencies.jar -aut your_apk.apk`

2.Open selendroid status URL http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/status and find out your appID.

3.Use this app id to install app on your device in

> SelendroidCapabilities capa = new
>   SelendroidCapabilities("io.selendroid.testapp:0.8.0");